# Docker and high performance cluster (HPC) ability

Tags: docker, hpc, swarm

i'm searching a possibility to get the power of 4 HPC-Nodes combined. The nodes are exactly the same, 32 Cores, 128GB RAM. The idea is to give students of our university the possibility to deploy there containers and run there programs on it.

I've read something about Docker Machine and Swarm, but it's more like Highly Availability.. Any ideas? :)

Kind regards,
Sub

Answer (score 0):

be aware that the docker daemon runs as root, therefore granting users to mount the host as root...

see
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30754910/771372