# Is there a "multi-user" Docker mode, e.g. for scientific clusters?

Tags: docker, singularity-container

I want to use Docker for isolating scientific applications for the use in a HPC Unix cluster. Scientific software often has exotic dependencies so isolating them with Docker appears to be a good idea. The programs are to be run as jobs and not as services.

I want to have multiple users use Docker and the users should be isolated from each other. Is this possible?

I performed a local Docker installation and had two users in the docker group. The call to `docker images` showed the same results for both users.

Further, the jobs should be run under the calling users's UID and not as root.

Is such a setup feasible? Has it been done before? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Intersiting idea, but with only docker I can't see a solution. Have you looked up management tools like http://shipyard-project.com/. Possible you can change there usermangement to make it usable for you.

Comment: Supercomputing clusters often use MPI for distributing the processing load, so I think any containers would have be able to access the MPI socket. Singularity, mentioned below, looks promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I think there will be more and more solutions pop up for this. I'll try to update the following list in the future:

- [udocker](https://github.com/indigo-dc/udocker) for executing Docker containers as users
- [Singularity](http://singularity.lbl.gov/index.html) (Kudos to Filo) is another Linux container based solution

Answer (score 6):

Yes there is! It's called Singularity and it was designed with scientific applications and multi user HPCs. More at http://singularity.lbl.gov/

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about DinD (Docker in Docker): [`jpetazzo/dind`](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind)

You could dedicate one Docker per user, and within one of those docker containers, the user could launch a job in a docker container.

Comment: Be aware that a dind container needs to run with --privileged flag, so it will probably be trivial for an attacker to break isolation (e.g. by mounting devices).

Answer (score 1):

I'm also interested in this possibility with Docker, for similar reasons. 
There are a few of problems I can think of:

1. The Docker Daemon runs as root, providing anyone in the docker group
   with effective host root permissions (e.g. leak permissions by
   mounting host / dir as root).
2. Multi user Isolation as mentioned
3. Not sure how well this will play with any existing load balancers?

I came across Shifter which may be worth a look an partly solves #1:
http://www.nersc.gov/research-and-development/user-defined-images/

Also I know there is discussion to use kernel user namespaces to provide mapping container:root --> host:non-privileged user but I'm not sure if this is happening or not.

Comment: Seems like user namespaces were dropped from Docker 1.7. Looks like they introduced a security issue due to the introduction of libnetwork, hoping they will land in v1.8

Answer (score 1):

There is an officially supported Docker image that allows one to run Docker in Docker (dind), available here: https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/. This way, each user can have their own Docker daemon. First, start the daemon instance:

```
docker run --privileged --name some-docker -d docker:stable-dins
```

Note that the `--privileged` flag is required. Next, connect to that instance from a second container:

```
docker run --rm --link some-docker:docker docker:edge version
```